# Scale AWS ECS Fargate up and down on specific time each day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a ECS Fargate service setup, which need to scale-up to 2 extra tasks on working hours i.e 9am to 5pm, otherwise I only need 1 task running.

I have tried [Scheduled tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html) but then I wont get to use my original ECS service with I use with "Application Load balancer".

I also tried ECS Service Auto scaling-'Step scaling' using a custom CloudWatch alarm. But I don't know any easy way to create a alarm to trigger on specific time, as ECS Step scaling does not accept EventBridge rule.

Comment: Is it not possible to run two separate services? One with the task that runs continuously and one with two tasks which are started every hour with a cloudwatch event rule

Comment: The two answers below describe the CLI and CFN solutions... as of october 2023 you cannot do this from the AWS console.  feature request here : https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1237

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use scheduled scaling:

```
aws application-autoscaling put-scheduled-action --service-namespace ecs \
    --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount \
    --resource-id service/${CLUSTER_NAME}/${SERVICE_NAME} \
    --scheduled-action-name ${DESIRED_ACTION_NAME} \
    --schedule "cron(cron-expression-to-add-here)" \ 
    --scalable-target-action MinCapacity=${MIN_CAPACITY_NEEDED_AT_DESIRED_TIME},MaxCapacity=${MAX_CAPACITY_NEEDED_AT_DESIRED_TIME}
```

You can have more info about `put-scheduled-action` [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/put-scheduled-action.html)

Comment: Absolute hidden gem, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Scheduled tasks will not work, as those tasks are not part of your service. ECS Scheduled tasks are for scheduled background tasks that run and exit on their own, not for a service that will be running indefinitely.

ECS Service Auto Scaling is the correct feature to use for this. Unfortunately the web interface lags behind the actual capabilities of the service, and doesn't allow you to configure scheduled scaling events at this time.

You currently have to use something like the AWS CLI tool to configure this via the API. You will need to create an AWS Application Autoscaling Target which references your ECS service's `DesiredCount` setting. Then you will need to create multiple AWS Application Autoscaling Scheduled Actions to change the min/max capacity values on a cron schedule.

I've done this before using Terraform so I know it is possible. And I highly recommend using Terraform to configure this, as well as the rest of your infrastructure. When ECS scheduled auto scaling is setup the configuration doesn't appear anywhere in the AWS web interface as far as I can find. The feature seems to be totally missing from both the ECS and Application Autoscaling web interfaces at this time.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for your answer. I tried to find the ECS scheduled auto scaling I've created with Terraform on the console but couldn't find anywhere. This helps me to validate that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of doing it in cloudformation - scaling a service we only need during business hours.  Note that I'm in australia so the crontab is GMT+10

```
ServiceAdmin:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    etc etc 

ServiceScalableTargetAdmin:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    MaxCapacity: 3
    MinCapacity: 1
    ResourceId: !Join
      - /
      - - service
        - ecs-cluster-admin
        - !GetAtt ServiceAdmin.Name
    RoleARN: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/ecs.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_ECSService
    ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
    ServiceNamespace: ecs
    # scale down admin environment overnight/weekends.  check it like this : aws application-autoscaling describe-scheduled-actions --service-namespace ecs
    ScheduledActions:
      - ScalableTargetAction:
          MaxCapacity: 0
          MinCapacity: 0
        Schedule: "cron(0 0 9 ? * MON-FRI *)"  #  that's 1900 MON-FRI brisbane time (2000 sydney summertime)
        ScheduledActionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-scale-down-overnight
      - ScalableTargetAction:
          MaxCapacity: 3
          MinCapacity: 1
        Schedule: "cron(0 0 19 ? * MON-FRI *)"  #  that's 0700 MON-FRI brisbane time (0800 sydney summertime)
        ScheduledActionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-scale-up-business-hours
```